# Site collection administration section is not present

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I just got to support a new Sharepoint Site. I created a new Site Collection scoped feature and deployed it. The things is that when I went to site settings to activate it. Site collection administration section is not there. I went to see the Site collection list in for the web application and there's only one, with no site collection admin section there.

How can I access that part of the administration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the user I was using to connect to the site did not have permissions to view Site Collection settings section.

I used another user and voila.